# Are Azure database DTU and Azure search Index related?

Tags: azure, search, service

Are Azure SQL database DTU and Azure search Index related? because in my application DTU % is going till 100% however in the code we have written a logic to update searchservice with datasource, Index and Index. Updation is done with first delete then create datasource, Index and Indexer.

When we call Search service manually by hitting controller for searchservice it deletes Index but does not create again and it is happening on staging level. I can not debug the code. I have tried the same scenario locally but it works fine on local.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database transaction units (DTUs) are not directly related to Azure Search indexes. However, in my opinion, I would think the DTUs would be impacted if you have an Azure Search Indexer that is mapped to an Azure SQL database. I haven't tested this. However, I would assume that if an indexer is running on a schedule, that would impact your DTUs when your search index is getting updated.

You may want to read up on indexers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Indexer-operations?redirectedfrom=MSDN).